# Logitech Wireless mk270r : Convert into Wired Keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, desktop-computer, computer-building, wireless-keyboard

Is it possible to make Logitech Wireless mk270r into a Wired Keyboard? Does any accessory or USB cable exist to convert it?

[https://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Wireless-mk270r-Keyboard-Mouse/dp/B00CEQEGPI/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CEQEGPI)

[image]

Comment: Probably not. Some keyboards with USB charging ports will work wired, but that one just takes regular batteries. Why do you want it wired? If it's a matter of transmission distance, you could extend the antenna dongle on a long USB cable. I use similar to place the dongle under my sofa to use the keyboard with a HTPC.

Comment: Cheaper and more trouble-free to get a wired keyboard.